# Why cant I connect to cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra

I have a basic cassandra setup on my laptop, its up and I can connect to it using the command line tools, however in java, the following fails:

```
Cluster cluster = new Cluster.Builder().addContactPoints("localhost").withPort(9160).build();
```

Any clues would be really helpful, thanks! The error is:

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: localhost/127.0.0.1 ([localhost/127.0.0.1] Unexpected error during transport initialization (com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [localhost/127.0.0.1] Channel has been closed)))
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:186)
```

Comment: Im having no problems using the cassandra jdbc library either.

Comment: I know I might sound stupid, but is Cassandra running?

Comment: @Chiron It doesn't, that is exactly the problem. @Jacob verify that cassandra is running by using `telnet 127.0.0.1 9160`

Comment: check the logfiles of cassandra for errors and warnings

Comment: check if the interface settings in the configuration of cassandra are correct: if you want cassandra to listen on more than one ip-adress (which is the case if you want to use localhost AND the ip-adress specified for the network connection) then you have to use 0.0.0.0 as Ip-Adress in the config.

Comment: It IS running, I mentioned I can connect to it from the command line. And I did try telnet that way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like your cassandra server isn't running. Check that the server is running via the task manager or `telnet 127.0.0.1 9160`

If you get the below cassandra isn't running:

```
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

As for the jdbc library, 1st piece of advice, use the DataStax driver (you can just add a [maven dependency](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.cassandra)), second piece of advice... use maven for jdbc too. Add the dependency into a maven project and then used [the code page on the wiki](https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-jdbc/).

Dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache-extras.cassandra-jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks. I did already try that.

Comment: Turns out restarting Cassandra fixed it, don't know why, but it did.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations, what to check if cassandra is running? I am using ssh tunnel and telnet is working  for both ports 9160 and 9042, but still I cannot connect, not by java app nor datastax devcenter with the same error(NoHostAvailable).

Comment: @LadyWoodi ssh into the server and try running cqlsh (its in the bin/ directory) If it connects C* is running, if not, open up cassandra.yaml (in the conf/ directory) and check your listen_address then try (again from the local server) ./cqlsh listen_address (e.g.: ./cqlsh 192.168.1.100)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that Cassandra is running! :)