# Cassandra connection fails

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu, cassandra, telnet

Error is

```
Exception in thread "main" com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /172.17.1.XX:9160 (com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/172.17.1.XX:9160] Cannot connect))
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:196)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:80)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1145)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.getMetadata(Cluster.java:313)
    at com.example.cassandra.Client.connect(Client.java:18)
    at com.example.cassandra.Client.main(Client.java:74)
```

Version of datastax is `dse 4.5.2`

Line where error occurs is `connect(node)`

```
   cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(node).withPort(9160).build();
   Metadata metadata = cluster.getMetadata(); //Error at this line
```

Call to the function is

```
     public static void main(String a[])
     {
       System.out.println("I am in");
       Client client = new Client();
       client.connect("172.17.1.XX");
       client.close();
     }
```

pom.xml is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0   http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.example.cassandra</groupId>
<artifactId>simple-client</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>0.1.0</version>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
   <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.0</version>
  </dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache-extras.cassandra-jdbc</groupId>
  <artifactId>cassandra-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.5</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
   <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.2</version>
      <configuration>
        <mainClass>com.example.cassandra.Client</mainClass>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
     <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
     </plugins>
   </build>
  </project>
```

I reffered [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18146781/why-cant-i-connect-to-cassandra)

Then i tried

```
 telnet 172.17.1.XX 9160

 Trying 172.17.1.XX...
 Connected to 172.17.1.XX.
 Escape character is '^]'.
```

If i type something, it says `connection closed by foreign agent`

```
 netstat -plten
```

on 172.17.1.XX

```
shows 

 tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8984          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          73148094    19145/java
 tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          73148635    19145/java
 tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7199            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          73148631    19145/java
 tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50370           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          73148632    19145/java
 tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9160            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          73148104    19145/java
 tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:33935           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          73148630    19145/java
 tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9042            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          73148103    19145/java
 tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8983            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          73148083    19145/java
```

So how do i solve this issue? Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're connecting to the wrong port: Java Driver connects to the Native Port (usually 9042) and not the Thrift Port (usually 9160). Change this line

```
cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(node).withPort(9042).build();
```

Comment: So if i need to use in docker container, do i need to expose this port? Where can i modify this port?

Comment: Yes you must expose this port. It's configurable in the cassandra.yaml file.